# How does JPA responds to scalability

Tags: java, jpa, scalability, jta

does anyone know if JPA is a good approach to a scalable environment? (i.e web application in a cluster, or several clusters), if not what is a good approach?

Thanks

edit: I changed JTA for JPA, I think the question makes more sense now.

Comment: depends on many things...idea is to strike the balance for your needs and requirements...the question is very generic

Comment: "JTA" doesn't respond to scalability, an implementation does. It's the JEE standard; what other options are you considering, and why?

Comment: Hi, I'm making a web application in java, and I intend to use Hibernate, but a friend of mine told me that Hibernate isn't very good at handling memory, so I investigated a little, and didn't find anything, so I considered using DAOs, but I think it's worse.

Comment: There is somewhat similar post, although not exactly about the same issues, of Adam Bien's: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/is_it_worth_using_pojos

Remember that "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" - D. Knuth.

Just develop your application, do some tests and then decide if this meets your requirements.

Comment: You're confusing JPA (Java Persistence Architecture) and JTA (Java Transaction API). Hibernate is an implementation of JPA, and applications using JPA typically use JTA as a way to demarcate transactions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I certainly got confused there, but I initially meant JPA.

Comment: JPA is just a way to access a database using a higher abstraction layer. You can make scalable applications with it, and it can also fail miserably. Just as with any other technology. It's not inherently unscalable. You just have to understand how it works and use it correctly. Just as any other technology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find implementations of JPA built into many world-class Java EE application servers — for example, JBoss has its Hibernate, Websphere — OpenJPA. They're scalable and capable of running in clusters. This fact alone should let you sleep well, or at least not to be concerned with it on a general level.

Comment: Also Oracle WebLogic uses EclipseLink, and Glassfish uses EclipseLink, also refer to http://www.spec.org/jEnterprise2010/ the main Java EE benchmark that heavily uses JPA